# Why Am i standing in a global minimum?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I`been asked the following in optimization

If I am located in a point where all the possible factible directions turn out to be worse for the function, Am I located in a global minimum? The answer is NO, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Depends if a local minima is any better? Since in optimisation this is tricky issue when trying to find minima also :). But I am not too sure if this is what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this plot descripes very well whats's meant here.

[image]

If you are at the green point, it seems like it gets worse no matter what way you go, however there are better points, like the red point, you just have to pass over a bump.